# Convert NIFTI file to META Format

Tags: c++, vtk, nifti

I start to work with C++ and VTK libraries and I'm trying to build this tutorial: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Medical/GenerateModelsFromLabels
The input argumentn (for me is a NIFTI file) must be in META Format but I don't understand how convert my NIFTI file in this META Format with VTK libraries.
Any ideas? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the nifti file with vtkNIFTIImageReader instead of vtkMetaImageReader

Comment: Thanks! I thought Meta format was necessary but it works!! :)

Comment: No, VTK supports multiple image formats :) If you really want metaimage, you can then write the image with .mhd or .mha extensions (either with vtk code or in softwares like slices or itksnap)

Comment: If this solved your question, can you accept the answer?